# Regex to match text, but not if contained in brackets

Tags: regex

I could not find any practical way to do this, myself:

**APPLE** should be matched

**APPLE APPLE** should result in two matches

**APPLE (APPLE)** should result in one match

**(BANANA APPLE)** should result in no matches

**()APPLE()** should result in one match

The brackets can be separated from the wanted string by any length of text over multiple lines. Other brackets not containing the string can exist in any configuration.

**EDIT** None of the answers thus far (and thanks for them!) allow for newline characters between the brackets. Is this not a possibility?

Comment: So, what have you tried? What is the final result you need to get (replacing apples outside of parentheses or getting a list of matches)?

Comment: @PavneetSingh Almost! That one still has issues with ()APPLE() though. I'll add that one to my list specifically.

Comment: This question was just downvoted, any idea why?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm sorry, but the linked question is NOT the same. That question is in fact the inverse of what is trying to be achieved here.

Comment: It is exactly the same. It contains a much  better, more versatile solution and is more helpful for future visitors.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If you haven't already vtd, this page is seeking one more.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hope this will work fine

Regex: `(?<!\()\bAPPLE\b(?![\w\s]*[\)])`

`\b` a word boundary

`(?![\w\s]*[\)])` Negatively lookahead for `) followed by words or spaces`

`(?<!\()` Negatively lookbehind for `(`

[RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/e2dw0k/6)

Comment: That.... works... I feel silly to ask, but can you explain exactly how that doesn't exclude, for example, ()APPLE()?

Comment: @WeckarE. Refer to http://regexr.com/ See Reference > Groups & Lookaround

Comment: This one still seems foiled if there are newline characters between the brackets. I cannot accept this answer yet. Thanks for the aid thus far though :)

Comment: @SahilGulati try to clarify the OP by copying and pasting important sections from a url in your answer

Comment: This regular expression say: `\b` for boundry line, `(?![\)])` for negatively looking ahead for `)` and firstpart `(?<!\()` says to negatively look behind for `(`

Comment: good and keep it in all your answers. Upvoted

Comment: A fine explanation, thanks. Is there any way for this to look across lines, though? I'm afraid that to allow newlines between the brackets would force a random amount of anychars; leading to full document matches no matter what.

Comment: @WeckarE. Welcome.. Looking into that.

Comment: @SahilGulati what if `(BANANA APPLE what? no! it's not working :P should)` ?

Comment: Actually, I hadn't tried @siam's scenario yet... Not sure why that's being tricky... Im still willing to accept it because question marks should never appear in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Try this Regex (if you don't need javascript regex):

```
(?<!\()\b\w+\b(?![\)])
```

[See Explanation and try Demos](https://regex101.com/r/tbqcfi/1)

---

You may have some complex texts between `(..\n..)`. So I suggest:

1- Add `)` in beginning and `(` to end of string! wait!

2- split your text with this regex `/\)[^\(]*\b(\w+)\b[^\)]*\(/` or execute this regex, two similar ways!

3- you've extract texts out of parenthesis and you can use `/\b\w+\b/` to match your words in out of parenthesis in Original text. `/\bAPPLE\b/` is for APPLE.

for example:

```js
var mytext = "Long text (for finding APPLE word and maybe replace\n"+
"by bold APPLE or something else!)\n"+
"So if APPLE APPLE and APPLE appear out of parenthesis\n"+
"they should convert to bold APPLE !" ;   
mytext = ")" + mytext + "(" ;

var r= new RegExp(/\)[^\(]*\b(\w+)\b[^\)]*\(/g);
var res = mytext.match(r) ;

console.log(res);

//for each matched item in res,
//  find APPLE and replace with new value
//   by this regex: /\b\w+\b/g
```

in this case, you will able to ignore APPLE in `"(BANANA APPLE what? no! it's not working :P should)"` or more complex texts!

Comment: This one still rejects a match if there is only a single bracket before it =/

Comment: You want find APPLE to do what next? please read new lines in my answer and let me know, does it helps to continue this way or not. @WeckarE.