# Is there a function to replace values with filters

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am trying to replace a string that is not surrounded by brackets. When I am using `string.Replace()`, it replaces all values (inside and outside of brackets). What should i use to replace values that is only outside of brackets?

Original string: `` "Example string: `REPLACEME` (`REPLACEME`)" ``

Required string: `` "Example string: `REPLACEMENT` (`REPLACEME`)" ``

P.S. I am not trying to replace first value from string, important here to replace value OUT OF BRACKETS

Comment: For now i collected all indexes of brackets and i can check if variable is inside it or not, but i still doesn't know how to make correct replacing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace first occurrence of pattern in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809354/replace-first-occurrence-of-pattern-in-a-string)

Comment: @Jawad I am not trying to replace first value from string, important here to replace value OUT OF BRACKETS. It can be first, second, XXX, doesnt matters what position is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42526951/regex-to-match-text-but-not-if-contained-in-brackets

Comment: You can always use the leading spaces in your favor: `Replace(" 'REPLACEME' ", " 'REPLACEMENT' ")`

Answer (score 1):

You could use following Regex with [Negavtive LookAhead and LookBehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<!\()\`\bREPLACEME\b\`(?![\w\s]*[\)])
```

For example,

```
var str = @"Example string: `REPLACEME` (`REPLACEME`)";
var result = Regex.Replace(str,@"(?<!\()\`\bREPLACEME\b\`(?![\w\s]*[\)])","`REPLACEMENT`");
```

Where

`(?<!\()` : Negative Look Behind that matches the Character `(`

`(?![\)])`: Negative Lookahead  that matches the Character `)`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wpq3eh/3)

Comment: Thanks for answer. but i have one issue - it will match if there are something between

Example:
(random things here`REPLACEMENT` random things here)

Comment: @StrangePotato You should update your question with a **worst case** example string to describe your problem better - something like "foo( foo ) foofoo foo (foo )" should evaluate to "bar( foo ) barbar bar (foo )"